# How to change a request in http java filter?

Tags: java, filter, servlet-filters

I have a filter. The filter execute when the url is www.example.com/filter/*

```
public class FilterOne implements Filter{


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
            String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();

            requestURI = StringUtils.substringAfter(requestURI, contextPath);
          //do things


            // HERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE REQUEST , I WANT TO DO A GET TO http://www.example.com


            String newURI = requestURI;


    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How i can change the request please ? 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to fetch data from another url with a subrequest and return that in the response?

Comment: I want to retrieve data from incoming url and go to the home page.

Comment: You already forward the request. Do you want to send a "redirect" response instead?

Comment: I update my code, i remove the forward. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What was wrong with the forward? It does what you want, doesn't it? If not, what does it not do that you would like it to do? If you want the URL in the browser address bar to change, then you need to send a redirect.